# Slow Transitions in react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using React-Native-Router-Flux for navigations in my react native project. When I move from screen A -> B such that screen B has network call, the transition is not smooth. There is a noticeable lagging in the transition.
Any suggestions how I can make the transition more smooth?
And, I'm very deep into the project with very strict deadlines, so changing the whole navigation will be very tough for me. My router component looks like-

```
<Scene key="drawer" component={Drawer} open={false} type="replace" initial={this.state.flag ? false : true}>
     <Scene key="root">
         <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="HOME" initial hideNavBar type="replace" />
         <Scene key="dashboard" component={Dashboard} hideNavBar={true} title="MENU DETAILS" />
         <Scene key="order" component={Order} hideNavBar={true} title="ORDER SUMMARY" />
    </Scene>
</Scene>
```

Now, I use `Actions.dashboard()` on a button click to move to dashboard, where I have a network call in `componentDidMount()` which fetches the data and dispatches an action to update the reducer and as a result returns a new state.
Similarly, in `Order` component, I'm making network call in `componentDidMount()` and this time I simply do `this.setState({data})` to update the component with the fetched data.
In both the navigation, `Home -> Dashboard` and `Home -> Order`, I'm having this "not smooth" transition.

Comment: Where are you making the network call?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried so far. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for creating well-asked questions.

Comment: @MattyK14 in componentDidMount.

Comment: @bennygenel I have a normal router component "Router.js". How is writing code relevant here?

Comment: You are talking about a network call. Where is that call? what else you have in those components? How do you trigger the navigation? These are all relevant because these are the parts where you can have performance issues.

Comment: @bennygenel will this much suffice?

Comment: Please check [Interaction Manager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html). Might help about the transition.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while running in Android. Just **stop the JS Remote Debugging** and try it  again it will then have smooth transition. I had this problem while signing in with auth with firebase. But its solved now!